# Do confidence intervals make sense for win rates in sport?

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, estimators

Imagine we have 2 teams play 10 matches against each other with team A winning 6 of them I.e. 60%. In this setting do confidence intervals for the probability of winning make sense? On one hand I would argue that we are estimating the data generation process in which the confidence intervals capture the uncertainty of the estimates in such a process. On the other these 10 matches are the full population that is we have all the data, surely there are no population parameters to be estimated as we know them?

Comment: Confidence intervals matter when we want to estimate something. What do you want to estimate? You already have the win rate and know it exactly, so you can’t want to estimate that value.

Comment: I would argue these ten games are just a sample of potential million games these two teams could play (in the future)

Comment: I guess I would argue that I am estimating the data generation process. Likewise from a statement point of view if you didn’t generate confidence intervals it feels like you are ignoring uncertainty I.e. do this mean that you can conclude that team A is definitively better than team B, what if they had only played 3 games? I think I would argue the population is the infinite number of potential games that could be played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can estimate a confidence interval for the probability of team A winning against team B by estimating a binomial proportion confidence interval. This assumes there is some constant underlying probability with which team A wins against team B.